# GLEW library types

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, glew, mingw-w64

I have just managed to successfully install OpenGL, GLFW3, and GLEW using CMake to build and MinGW to compile various libraries, finally (after much trial and error) allowing me to move on and learn how to actually use the libraries.

The last issue that I ran into was a simple "undefined reference to `_imp__glewInit@0'" -- something which I had seen many times before (with other libraries) and led me to believe that I had not added "libglew32.a" to MinGW's library folder, or possibly that I needed to add "-l glew32" to my g++ command. Neither of these were the issue. I then browsed this site for possible solutions, the most promising of which suggested that I add "#define GLEW_STATIC" immediately before my call to "#include < GL\glew.h >". This solved nothing.

I started trying random things at this point, and the solution that I stumbled into was to use the "libglew32.dll.a" instead of "libglew32.a". Even this didn't find the glew32.dll that I had put in System32, and so I'm having to put glew32.dll in either SysWOW64, or in my project's folder for it to be found.

This leaves me with a few questions about how libraries and linking works in C++/Windows, because up until this speed bump, I thought I had developed a decent understanding of the process:

- Why was the linker not able to find glewInit() when I had "libglew32.a" in MinGW's library folder and "-l glew32" added to the compile command? This combination worked for OpenGL, GLUT, GLFW, GLU, GLM, etc..
- Why was the linker not able to find "glew32.dll" in System32? Again, this worked for other dynamic libraries that I had used in the past.

While this is not the most urgent of questions, I do wish to have a solid understanding of how C++ compilation & linking works, and how various types of libraries are used. I feel that a better understanding of this situation would help greatly.

Comment: `System32` keeps it's name for legacy reasons but on 64 bit systems is only for 64 bit binaries. When you run a 32 bit executable on Windows 64 bit you run in an "emulated" environment  and the `SysWOW64` is mapped onto where you would expecit the `System32` folder to be.  As you might expect there are many other changes as well.  More reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks for the info & link, good to know. I didn't even know I was compiling into a 32 bit exe, so I learned two things. I went back and looked at the installation instructions for MinGW-w64 and it turns out that "i686" architecture corresponds with 32-bit while "x86_64" corresponds with 64-bit. Didn't know this at the time; reinstalling.